# Accounting for two scenarios in lambda expressions within a for-each loop

Tags: java, lambda

As an exercise, I've decided to learn lambda expressions in Java. I'd like to rewrite my old code I find clumsy and long. It checks whether a command line argument is (1) a path to file or (2) a path to directory. In (1) scenario it passed in the command line argument to a method. In (2) scenario it checks if in a given directory there are `*.pdf` files, and then (and only then) passes in a path to each file. My code is as follows:

```
File file = new File(args[0]);
            if (file.exists()) {
                if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                    modifyPdf(args[0]);
                }
                else {
                    File[] files = new File(args[0]).listFiles((FileFilter) new WildcardFileFilter("*.pdf"));
                    if (files != null) {
                        for (File f : files) {
                            modifyPdf(f);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

}

I wrote a lambda expression that deals with (1) scenario.  However, I do not know how to account for (1) and (2) scenarios in one lambda expressions. My attempt at changing the code to lambda expressions is as follows:

```
for (Path path1 : Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(args[0]), path ->
            Files.isRegularFile(path)
                    && path.toString().endsWith(".pdf"))) {
        Class.meth(path1);
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Still very unclear. You want to deal with two situations: 1. the path points to a file, 2. the path points to a directory. Then what? What is "deal with two situations" mean? What is your code supposed to do?

Comment: If the processing for a directory is very different than the processing for a matching file, then you will have to repeat yourself somewhere.  Either have 2 loops or repeat the test for whether the path is a directory

Comment: @JBNizet I rewrote my questions. Perhaps now it is more clear.

Comment: I think you might find `Files.walkFileTree` method useful (seems like it can handle both file and directory seamlessly): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.util.Set,%20int,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void run() throws Exception
{
    Path rootDir = Paths.get("data");
    PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:**.pdf");

    Files.walk(rootDir)
         .filter(matcher::matches)
         .forEach(this::modifyPdf);
}

private void modifyPdf(Path p) {
    // Some code here...
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! It is working great. Is there an option that this method would not work recursively?

Comment: You can set the max depth in this overload.
[link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-)